# Pythonanywhere Django app does not work with MySql

Tags: python, mysql, django, pythonanywhere

What do we have:

1. Django app hosted on Pythonanywhere with sqlite db initialized
2. MySql DB activated on Pythonanywhere (it provided me with db name, pasword and host - everything that I need to setup settings.py)
3. pip install mysqlclient finished successfully
4. python manage.py makemigrations - DONE
5. python manage.py migrate - DONE
6. mysql console on Pythonanywhere shows all my tables created
7. but restarting app causes pythonanywhere error page and link to error log

```html
2020-08-15 17:22:56,536: Error running WSGI application
2020-08-15 17:22:56,569: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
2020-08-15 17:22:56,569: Did you install mysqlclient?
```

So the question is how could it be possible? As i got it right migrations are used mysqlclient to manipulate DB, how can it be not installed?

Might be someone did face with similar issue?

Comment: If you're using a virtualenv, are you sure that you pip installed mysqlclient into that virtualenv, and not into another one?  Have you reloaded the website from the "Web" page inside PythonAnywhere after doing the pip install?

Comment: It was exactly answer ! Many thanks. I forgot to switch to appropriate virtual env

Comment: Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to install mysql client, but that might also throw an error, so you need to install it using its wheels from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient) and keep installing every wheel incase an error occurs.